# How to monitor network requests of Chrome apps?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I’m interested in finding out exactly what network requests are made by certain 3rd party Chrome apps. I can open the Dev Tools from `chrome://inspect/#apps`, or from the context menu (enabled under `chrome://flags/#debug-packed-apps`), or by means of the Chrome Apps & Extensions Developer Tool. Whatever I do, the Network tab stays blank except an occasional image/png, while I’m sure lots of HTTP requests (or HTTPS to be exact) actually take place.

How can I monitor all network requests that an app makes? It seems easy for extensions, but not for standalone apps. Or is MITMing myself with a proxy with a self-signed certificate that Chrome is configured to trust the only option?